# BeagleBone AI - How to setup CAN bus

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, u-boot, can-bus

I couldn't find any resources on the internet for setting up CAN bus on the Beagle Bone AI, and I had a lot of trouble getting it up and going but zmatt on the http://beagleboard.org/chat basically did everything for me to help get this up and going, so, #1 please everyone thank zmatt, #2 i'd like to share my findings here so other people do not need to go through all the pain I went through to get this up and going.

The basic problem is that BeagleBone AI does not work out of the box with CAN bus. The main reason is that the pinxmux is not configured correctly, by default.

Steps to fix the problem:

Download a version of the Linux kernel for your device. I tested with:

```
 https://elinux.org/Beagleboard:Latest-images-testing
 am57xx-debian-10.3-console-armhf-2020-04-06-1gb.img.xz
```

Note: This is a "console" version, meaning you have to install all applications yourself. Basically, every time you try a command and it fails, google Linux install (whatever command fails). Otherwise, you could try one of the basic Beagle Bone AI distros which will include apps by default.

Setup your network configuration so you can download whatever you need in the BBAI. In my case, i'm connecting the BBAI to WIFI so connect it via:
      https://fis.gatech.edu/how-to-configure-bbw-wifi/

Download the device tree source code:

```
Note!!!! Which ever version of Linux you are using, you MUST make sure the source code branch you are using matches your Linux version!!!!
   cd ~
   mkdir DeviceTree
   #The following command will create a folder BeagleBoard-DeviceTrees in the current directory with the device tree.
   git clone https://github.com/beagleboard/BeagleBoard-DeviceTrees.git
   #For instance, if you are using version 4.14 of the TI linux, set the GIT branch to:
   #Note 2: make sure it is the TI version (-ti)
   git checkout v4.14.x-ti
```

Ok so here is the secret sauce. Use the following DTS that zmatt created. Save the file in ~/DeviceTree/BeagleBoard-DeviceTrees/src/arm/bbai-custom.dts

File contents:

```
#include "am5729-beagleboneai.dts"

&{/chosen} {
    base_dtb = "bbai-custom.dts";   // <-- name of this file goes here
};

#define P9_24   ( 0x3400 + 4 * 163 )
#define P9_26a  ( 0x3400 + 4 * 162 )
#define P9_26b  ( 0x3400 + 4 *  81 )

&dra7_pmx_core {
    can1_pins_active: can1-active {
        pinctrl-single,pins = <
            DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD( P9_24,  PIN_INPUT_PULLUP  | MUX_MODE2  ) // rx
            DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD( P9_26a, PIN_OUTPUT_PULLUP | MUX_MODE2  ) // tx
        >;
    };

    can1_pins_sleep: can1-sleep {
        pinctrl-single,pins = <
            DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD( P9_24,  PIN_OUTPUT_PULLUP | MUX_MODE15 ) // rx (disabled)
            DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD( P9_26a, PIN_OUTPUT_PULLUP | MUX_MODE15 ) // tx (disabled)
        >;
    };

    can1_pins_init: can1-init {
        pinctrl-single,pins = <
            DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD( P9_26b, PIN_OUTPUT        | MUX_MODE15 ) // disable unused shared pin
        >;
    };
};

&dcan2 {  // <---- not a typo
    status = "ok";
    pinctrl-names = "init", "default", "sleep", "active";
    pinctrl-0 = <&can1_pins_sleep>, <&can1_pins_init>;
    pinctrl-1 = <&can1_pins_sleep>;
    pinctrl-2 = <&can1_pins_sleep>;
    pinctrl-3 = <&can1_pins_active>;
};

// Here's the obnoxious part: since u-boot doesn't have same pin defaults yet, all pins not  
// explicitly setup above should be overridden here.  This will eventually no longer be needed.  
&cape_pins_default {
    pinctrl-single,pins = <
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x379C, MUX_MODE14) /* AB8: P8.3: mmc3_dat6.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x37A0, MUX_MODE14) /* AB5: P8.4: mmc3_dat7.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x378C, MUX_MODE14) /* AC9: P8.5: mmc3_dat2.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3790, MUX_MODE14) /* AC3: P8.6: mmc3_dat3.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x36EC, MUX_MODE14) /* G14: P8.7: mcasp1_axr14.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x36F0, MUX_MODE14) /* F14: P8.8: mcasp1_axr15.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3698, MUX_MODE14) /* E17: P8.9: xref_clk1.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x36E8, MUX_MODE14) /* A13: P8.10: mcasp1_axr13.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3510, MUX_MODE14) /* AH4: P8.11: vin1a_d7.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x350C, MUX_MODE14) /* AG6: P8.12: vin1a_d6.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3590, PIN_INPUT | MUX_MODE12) /* D3: P8.13: vin2a_d10.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3598, MUX_MODE14) /* D5: P8.14: vin2a_d12.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3570, MUX_MODE14) /* D1: P8.15a: vin2a_d2.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x35B4, MUX_MODE13) /* A3: P8.15b: vin2a_d19.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x35BC, MUX_MODE13) /* B4: P8.16: vin2a_d21.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3624, MUX_MODE14) /* A7: P8.17: vout1_d18.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3588, PIN_INPUT | MUX_MODE12) /* F5: P8.18: vin2a_d8.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x358C, PIN_INPUT | MUX_MODE12) /* E6: P8.19: vin2a_d9.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3780, MUX_MODE14) /* AC4: P8.20: mmc3_cmd.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x377C, MUX_MODE14) /* AD4: P8.21: mmc3_clk.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3798, MUX_MODE14) /* AD6: P8.22: mmc3_dat5.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3794, MUX_MODE14) /* AC8: P8.23: mmc3_dat4.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3788, MUX_MODE14) /* AC6: P8.24: mmc3_dat1.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3784, MUX_MODE14) /* AC7: P8.25: mmc3_dat0.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x35B8, MUX_MODE13) /* B3: P8.26: vin2a_d20.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x35D8, MUX_MODE14) /* E11: P8.27a: vout1_vsync.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3628, MUX_MODE14) /* A8: P8.27b: vout1_d19.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x35C8, MUX_MODE14) /* D11: P8.28a: vout1_clk.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x362C, MUX_MODE14) /* C9: P8.28b: vout1_d20.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x35D4, MUX_MODE14) /* C11: P8.29a: vout1_hsync.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3630, MUX_MODE14) /* A9: P8.29b: vout1_d21.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x35CC, MUX_MODE14) /* B10: P8.30a: vout1_de.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3634, MUX_MODE14) /* B9: P8.30b: vout1_d22.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3614, MUX_MODE14) /* C8: P8.31a: vout1_d14.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x373C, MUX_MODE14) /* G16: P8.31b: mcasp4_axr0.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3618, MUX_MODE14) /* C7: P8.32a: vout1_d15.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3740, MUX_MODE14) /* D17: P8.32b: mcasp4_axr1.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3610, MUX_MODE14) /* C6: P8.33a: vout1_d13.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x34E8, MUX_MODE14) /* AF9: P8.33b: vin1a_fld0.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3608, MUX_MODE14) /* D8: P8.34a: vout1_d11.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3564, MUX_MODE14) /* G6: P8.34b: vin2a_vsync0.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x360C, MUX_MODE14) /* A5: P8.35a: vout1_d12.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x34E4, MUX_MODE14) /* AD9: P8.35b: vin1a_de0.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3604, MUX_MODE14) /* D7: P8.36a: vout1_d10.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3568, MUX_MODE14) /* F2: P8.36b: vin2a_d0.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x35FC, MUX_MODE14) /* E8: P8.37a: vout1_d8.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3738, MUX_MODE14) /* A21: P8.37b: mcasp4_fsx.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3600, MUX_MODE14) /* D9: P8.38a: vout1_d9.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3734, MUX_MODE14) /* C18: P8.38b: mcasp4_aclkx.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x35F4, MUX_MODE14) /* F8: P8.39: vout1_d6.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x35F8, MUX_MODE14) /* E7: P8.40: vout1_d7.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x35EC, MUX_MODE14) /* E9: P8.41: vout1_d4.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x35F0, MUX_MODE14) /* F9: P8.42: vout1_d5.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x35E4, MUX_MODE14) /* F10: P8.43: vout1_d2.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x35E8, MUX_MODE14) /* G11: P8.44: vout1_d3.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x35DC, MUX_MODE14) /* F11: P8.45a: vout1_d0.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x361C, MUX_MODE14) /* B7: P8.45b: vout1_d16.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x35E0, MUX_MODE14) /* G10: P8.46a: vout1_d1.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3638, MUX_MODE14) /* A10: P8.46b: vout1_d23.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x372C, MUX_MODE14) /* B19: P9.11a: mcasp3_axr0.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3620, MUX_MODE14) /* B8: P9.11b: vout1_d17.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x36AC, MUX_MODE14) /* B14: P9.12: mcasp1_aclkr.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3730, MUX_MODE14) /* C17: P9.13: mcasp3_axr1.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x35AC, MUX_MODE10) /* D6: P9.14: vin2a_d17.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3514, MUX_MODE14) /* AG4: P9.15: vin1a_d8.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x35B0, MUX_MODE13) /* C5: P9.16: vin2a_d18.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x37CC, MUX_MODE14) /* B24: P9.17a: spi2_cs0.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x36B8, MUX_MODE14) /* F12: P9.17b: mcasp1_axr1.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x37C8, MUX_MODE14) /* G17: P9.18a: spi2_d0.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x36B4, MUX_MODE14) /* G12: P9.18b: mcasp1_axr0.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3440, PIN_INPUT_PULLUP | MUX_MODE7) /* R6: P9.19a: gpmc_a0.i2c4_scl */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x357C, PIN_INPUT_PULLUP | MUX_MODE12 ) /* F4: P9.19b: vin2a_d5.pr1_pru1_gpi2 */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3444, PIN_INPUT_PULLUP | MUX_MODE7) /* T9: P9.20a: gpmc_a1.i2c4_sda */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3578, PIN_INPUT_PULLUP | MUX_MODE12) /* D2: P9.20b: vin2a_d4.pr1_pru1_gpi1 */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x34F0, MUX_MODE14) /* AF8: P9.21a: vin1a_vsync0.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x37C4, MUX_MODE14) /* B22: P9.21b: spi2_d1.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x369C, MUX_MODE14) /* B26: P9.22a: xref_clk2.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x37C0, MUX_MODE14) /* A26: P9.22b: spi2_sclk.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x37B4, MUX_MODE14) /* A22: P9.23: spi1_cs1.off */
    //  DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x368C, MUX_MODE14) /* F20: P9.24: gpio6_15.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3694, MUX_MODE14) /* D18: P9.25: xref_clk0.off */
    //  DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3688, MUX_MODE14) /* E21: P9.26a: gpio6_14.off */
    //  DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3544, MUX_MODE14) /* AE2: P9.26b: vin1a_d20.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x35A0, MUX_MODE14) /* C3: P9.27a: vin2a_d14.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x36B0, MUX_MODE14) /* J14: P9.27b: mcasp1_fsr.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x36E0, MUX_MODE14) /* A12: P9.28: mcasp1_axr11.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x36D8, MUX_MODE14) /* A11: P9.29a: mcasp1_axr9.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x36A8, MUX_MODE14) /* D14: P9.29b: mcasp1_fsx.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x36DC, MUX_MODE14) /* B13: P9.30: mcasp1_axr10.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x36D4, MUX_MODE14) /* B12: P9.31a: mcasp1_axr8.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x36A4, MUX_MODE14) /* C14: P9.31b: mcasp1_aclkx.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x36A0, MUX_MODE14) /* C23: P9.41a: xref_clk3.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3580, MUX_MODE14) /* C1: P9.41b: vin2a_d6.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x36E4, MUX_MODE14) /* E14: P9.42a: mcasp1_axr12.off */
        DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x359C, MUX_MODE14) /* C2: P9.42b: vin2a_d13.off */
    >;
};
```

After saving the DTS text file, we need to compile it. The GIT repository allows us to compile this file easily.

To compile:

```
  cd ~/DeviceTree/BeagleBoard-DeviceTrees

  #This should create a bbai-custom.dtb file
  make src/arm/bbai-custom.dtb

  #Verify that the file ~/DeviceTree/BeagleBoard-DeviceTrees/src/arm/bbai-custom.dtb after compiling.
```

Move the output binary

```
  #Copy the output binary to the /boot directory so when we boot we can detect and use it.
  sudo cp src/arm/bbai-custom.dtb /boot/dtbs/bbai-custom.dtb
```

Modify the U-Boot boot setup file:

```
  #Use whatever text editor you like to modify the following file
  sudo nano /boot/uEnv.txt

  Add the following to the file
  dtb=bbai-custom.dtb

  Save the file
  Reboot the machine
```

Test that it works by typing in:

```
  #Type the following command in and can0 should be in the list
  ip link
```

Final warning! I tried to write down everything I did to get this setup but i'm not 100% positive that all of the above steps are explicitly right. Please read between the lines if I made some copy paste, path mistakes, or otherwise.

Hopefully all of this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I asked this question a few months ago (and later answered it myself on the BB mailing list): https://groups.google.com/d/msg/beagleboard/-0BqofMNKVw/FpOSb4rzAAAJ

I did essentially what you did but my .dts file is a shorter. I did not have to re-specify all other pins, it works just fine like this:

```
#include "am5729-beagleboneai.dts"

/ {
    chosen {
        base_dtb = "am5729-beagleboneai-kitepower.dts";
        base_dtb_timestamp = __TIMESTAMP__;
    };
};

// The second name (pinmux_dcan2_pins) seems not used
&dra7_pmx_core {
    dcan2_pins: pinmux_dcan2_pins {
        pinctrl-single,pins = <
            /* P9_24: uart1_txd.d_can2_rx */
            DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x368C, PIN_INPUT_PULLUP | MUX_MODE2)
            /* P9_26: uart1_rxd.d_can2_tx */
            DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD(0x3688, PIN_OUTPUT_PULLUP | MUX_MODE2)
        >;
    };
};

// Initially defined in dra7 (which is included through multiple layers) as disabled
&dcan2 {
    pinctrl-names = "default"; // Not sure what this is used for
    pinctrl-0 = <&dcan2_pins>;
    status = "okay";
};
```